# Intermittent FTP publish issue in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ftp, publishing

I am using the build in publishing tools of VS2010. I use this for a number of sites, however I have one that is occasionally problematic. I have everything saved and when I publish for the first time it always succeeds. Then when I go to publish again I get a successful build, but a failed publish. *Note that the publish directory is a sub-directory, as that is the structure of the hosting company.*

```
Connecting to ftp://www.website.com/Html/...
Unable to open the Web site 'ftp://www.website.com/Html'.  There is no site named "Html".
========== Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I close VS and restart it works. I feel this is probably a bug, but wanted to see if anyone else has had that experience and/or a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the host. Placed a ticket with them and they resolved. Do not know what resolution, but non-issue.